# How to subclass a uibutton and use a standard system image

Tags: uiview, uibutton, subclass

I would like to subclass a uibutton and redeclare a couple properties, but i don't want to change anything else. namely, I want to keep the standard plain system image provided.

is this possible or an attempt to eat cake and have the cake it tomorrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. If you want to redeclare use subclass if you want to add more functionality use Categories